# Integrate Cordova Plugin in Windows 8 Universal Application IBM MobileFirst

Tags: cordova, win-universal-app, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM MobileFirst Platform 7.1 and want to know how to integrate cordova plugin in Windows 8 Universal Application.

There is no config.xml and no plugin.xml. And also I am not able to add any native file like .cs file in the project as it is the Universal JS Project.

I want to know how should I proceed? or any link will also work.

Any guide or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 this is only officially supported in Windows Phone 8 apps - https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/adding-native-functionality/windows-phone-8-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/